# Prove that if $f'(a)<w<f'(b)$ then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=w$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Prove that if $f'(a)<w<f'(b)$ then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=w$

**My attempt:**

So I defined a new function $G(x)=f(x)-wx$. There is two cases here.

The first is that $G(x)$ has a local maxima or local minima in $(a,b)$, in which case, at that point $x_0$, since $G$ is differentiable, $G'(x_0)=0$ and the result follows.

The second is that $G(x)$ has no local maxima or minima in $(a,b)$, in which case, $G$ is injective, and hence with the continious injection theorem, $G$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Hence, $G'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ or $G'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$. However, this contradicts $G'(a)=f'(a)-w<0<f'(b)-w=G'(b)$

Hence, we will always have such point.

Is this proof sufficient? Any logic jumps?

Comment: Is this the [Darboux Theorem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)-w(x-a)$ then $g(a)=f(a)$ and $g(b)=f(b)-w(b-a). If g attains any local maxima or minima we are done. Thus we have f is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on (a,b). But this implies the contradiction you got

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Darboux's Theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis) ) states that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function then $f'$ has the Intermediate Value Property. 
This theorem can be proved by Rolle's theorem.